# Can't type backslash in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

When I type the backslash key on my keyboard, nothing happens in Notepad++

I have been using Notepad++ for years and only recently - I think I first noticed this a couple months ago - this started happening and I can't remember if this started after some upgrade.

I upgraded today to see if it would solve this problem but it didn't. So now I'm running the latest version.

I tested in Sublime Text, Office Word, and Windows Notepad, they all show the backslash character when I type the backslash key, so this problem seems to be related to Notepad++ only.

Comment: It's a very quick re-installation, safe bet to at least give that a shot. Possibly something got corrupted, and hopefully that would solve it for you.

Comment: Try changing the font at 'Settings' -> 'Style Configurator'. On the right side, it says 'Font name'. The default setting should be Courier New.

Comment: @thom :-), yes, so often we find that "*upgrades*" tend to do everything but *upgrade*...

Comment: @NicholasV. Maybe you could add your solution as an answer so that thom can accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very quick re-installation, safe bet to at least give that a shot. Possibly something got corrupted, and hopefully that would solve it for you.

While there is something else at the root cause of this issue, re-installing of a program tends to be a sure-fire way to solve.